# "Blog pages show at most" in setting not working

Tags: posts, homepage, blog, blog-page, home-url

After the update to the new WordPress version, "***Blog pages show at most***" (*Setting >> Reading*) is not working. Even if I change the count as 5 there, the homepage shows 10 articles i. It is not changing even I change to any count.

[image]

For more information,
I have two blogs that have the same theme and same WordPress version. One blog has 150 articles, and the other has 300 articles. 300+ article blogs faced this issue. Are there any changes that happen after publishing 300+ articles in WordPress? List 10 articles must show on the home screen as default?
Any idea to solve this issue ?

I have found this code in the function.php
is there anything to change

```
**
* Check if Latest Posts are being displayed on homepage and set 
  posts_per_page accordingly
*/
            function mts_home_posts_per_page( $query ) {
                global $mts_options;

                if ( ! $query->is_home() || ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
                    return;
                }

                $set_posts_per_page = 0;
                if ( ! empty( $mts_options['mts_featured_categories'] ) ) {
                    foreach ( $mts_options['mts_featured_categories'] as $section ) {
                        if ( 'latest' === $section['mts_featured_category'] ) {
                            $set_posts_per_page = $section['mts_featured_category_postsnum'];
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if ( ! empty( $set_posts_per_page ) ) {
                    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', $set_posts_per_page );
                }
            }
            add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'mts_home_posts_per_page' );

            // Map images and categories in group field after demo content import.
            add_filter( 'mts_correct_single_import_option', 'mts_correct_homepage_sections_import', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: This would have something to do with your theme’s front page template. You will need to discuss this with your theme’s author.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I cannot contact him. Is there anything general thing I need to check with the theme homepage? If you give me an idea, i can check with that

Comment: You would need to look at the code of the template used for the front page, and see what the code does. There's a chance that your theme simply doesn't support what you're trying to do. It's not possible to be certain without seeing the code of the theme,

Comment: @JacobPeattie I have updated with a code, is there anything i can do with it ?

Comment: As a test, you could comment out the function ```mts_home_posts_per_page()``` or just comment out the call to ```add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'mts_home_posts_per_page' )``` to see if that changes the behavior you are seeing. I also suggest checking to see if there are any options with the theme you are using to control how many posts are presented at one time on the homepage of your site.

Comment: @ScottM I have comment the `add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'mts_home_posts_per_page' )`  code and it works fine. Thank you. 
Im  just curious why the developer add this code. There are no such a theme options to control it. Any idea about it ?

Comment: It does look as though it is checking for a setting somewhere in the theme rather than using the WP setting though... ....I find a lot of third party/commercial themes have really illogical and confusing settings, I'd recommend going through them all again to see where that option is set.  Re-writing the theme code isn't stable because if there's an update you'll have to re-write the code again.